# Reminders App runs randomly

Tags: macos, reminders

I have a MacBook Air running El Capitan 10.11.1. Since the upgrade, the Reminders App runs randomly. I have already deleted all reminders (even removed the scheduled ones) but the behaviour continues. The app comes up without any notification, but just in case I also disabled all notifications.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Well, at least I'm not the only one...